# Load Assembly Sources into IDA

Tags: reverse-engineering, assembly

I have a large codebase written in assembly that I need to maintain.

Exploring the existing code is tough with text editor's syntax highlighting being the only helping tool.

I was considering to use IDA tool to assist with this task. It has many nice features for exploring assembly code. So I downloaded the free 5.0 version for evaluation.

Unfortunately, I am unable to locate an option that provide the ability to open an assembly **source** file. All the "open" options do is to dissasmble binaries, but this is useless to me as I already have the source code inclding all the comments and human readable symbols.

It is hard to believe that a tool with so many features lacks this basic capability. So what am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IDA, as stated at its [website](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml), is a [Disassembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler). It was developed to find out what a program does **WITHOUT** the assistance of the source code, not the other way around. Why should anyone try to employ the complex and time-consuming techniques available in IDA to discover what a binary does if all they have to do is take a peek at the original code?

IDA is **NOT** a development tool, it is a **reverse-engineering** tool. You should look for an Assembly IDE for the task you seek to complete. Maybe [RadASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RadASM) provides what you are looking for.

Comment: Maintaining assembly code is very similar to reverse-engineering. In both disciplines you have to read and understand code written by others. The difference is that if you have the sources you do not need to fight obfuscation and there are symbols and (sometimes) comments which help you with understanding.
I understand that the purpose of the IDA tool is reverse-engineering, but I was hoping I could use it as a source browser as well. For this purpose it have advantages over assembly IDE's available on the market which are mere text editors with syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Artium Did you figure out ?

Comment: Sorry @franck, no luck. We ended up customizing Notepad++ for this purpose. This is a pity as many unique IDA's features, such as flow graphs, might have been useful to us.

Comment: @Artium did you release the customizing by any chance ?